# flutter error:The argument type 'Future<Image>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'

Tags: dart, flutter

i'm using flutter flame library and got this error

> ```
> The argument type 'Future<Image>' can't be assigned to the parameter
> type 'Widget'.
> ```

my code is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flame/flame.dart';

class TileMap extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TileMapState createState() => _TileMapState();
}

class _TileMapState extends State<TileMap> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Flame.images.load('grass_05.png'),
    );
  }
}
```

how to fix it?
and what's the problem?
thank's to all

Answer (score 1):

```
class _TileMapState extends State<TileMap> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadImage()
  }

  void _loadImage() async {
    var img = await Flame.images.load('grass_05.png');
    setState(() => _image = img);
  }

  Image _image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: _image,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to use more of flame's features, consider using a BaseGame instance and get the widget from that :)